# Issue when deploying to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Have someone faced an issue like this when deploying a project on Heroku?

```
Bundle complete! 40 Gemfile dependencies, 103 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
       Bundle completed (3.58s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
       Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.13.7) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.14.6). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
       Removing bundler (1.11.2)
-----> Installing node-v6.10.0-linux-x64
-----> Detecting rake tasks
sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
 !
 !     Could not detect rake tasks
 !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
 !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
 !     rake aborted!
 !     LoadError: libdmtx.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /tmp/build_07af0b8150c4d2d6b3e8cd1198b88169/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/Rdmtx-0.2.2/Rdmtx.so
 !     /tmp/build_07af0b8150c4d2d6b3e8cd1198b88169/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
```

I'm able to use the application locally and I can run  `$ bundle exec rake -P against` my app as well.

PS: Just before this deploy I was having issues with libdmtx as I posted here: [Issues with gem Rdmtx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43860050/issues-with-gem-rdmtx/43862962#43862962)

Answer (score 0):

Something very similar happened to me, and everything was due to the temporary files of the project, I see that you have a similar error:

```
LoadError: libdmtx.so.0: can not open shared object file: /tmp/build_07af0b8150c4d2d6b3e8cd1198b88169/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/Rdmtx-0.2 .2 / Rdmtx.so ! /tmp/build_07af0b8150c4d2d6b3e8cd1198b88169/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require '
```

What I did was erase them and ran the Bundle again and go, try

Comment: The problem is that it is happening in Heroku and as far as I know it is not possible to clean heroku's tmp folder.

Comment: If you are right, what I say you can try is to delete the temporary files in local, run the Bundle Install again and then deploy back to heroku, it may be that as you had some gems with this data are stored in these temporary files

Comment: I clean the tmp using `rake tmp:clear` and deploy the code again, but the issue remains. It seems that heroku is not able to find that lib.

Answer (score 0):

It was necessary to add this buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt.